# How do I define a generic member variable in an enum?

Tags: java, generics, enums

I want to reference an enum method to retrieve the class of an algorithm so that I can lazy-load a new instance of the algorithm for use in the strategy design pattern.

In this example, I am using an enum to reference three different strategy classes that calculate Fibonacci numbers: `RecursiveFibonacciGenerator`, `IterativeFibonacciGenerator`, and `MemoizedFibonacciGenerator` (all of which inherit from `FibonacciGenerator`).

The code (with lines generating errors commented with intent) is as follows:

```
package com.example.strategy;

public class Fibonacci {
    private enum Algorithm {
        RECURSIVE (RecursiveFibonacciGenerator.class),
        ITERATIVE (IterativeFibonacciGenerator.class),
        MEMOIZED (MemoizedFibonacciGenerator.class);

        private final Class<T> algorithmClass; // Declare class of same type as constructor
        private final T instance; // Declare instance of class defined in constructor
        private <T extends FibonacciGenerator> Algorithm(Class<T> algorithmClass) {
            this.algorithmClass = algorithmClass;
        }

        public T getInstance() {
            if (this.instance == null) {
                this.instance = this.algorithmClass.newInstance();
            }
            return this.instance;
        }
    }

    public Integer getTerm(Integer termNumber) {
        profileGenerator(termNumber, Algorithm.RECURSIVE);
        profileGenerator(termNumber, Algorithm.ITERATIVE);
        return profileGenerator(termNumber, Algorithm.MEMOIZED);
    }

    private Integer profileGenerator(Integer termNumber, Algorithm algorithm) {
        System.out.print("Computing term using " + algorithm.toString() + " algorithm... ");
        Long startTimeMilliseconds = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Integer term = algorithm.getInstance().generateTerm(termNumber);
        Long endTimeMilliseconds = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Long computationTimeMilliseconds = endTimeMilliseconds - startTimeMilliseconds;
        System.out.println("term computed in " + computationTimeMilliseconds + " milliseconds");
    }
}
```

I would like to know how I can use this `enum` constructor to store a member variable of the `Class<T>` type.

**Edit:** Added full code to clarify intent

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
public enum Algorithm {
    RECURSIVE(FibonacciGenerator.RecursiveFibonacciGenerator.class),
    ITERATIVE(FibonacciGenerator.IterativeFibonacciGenerator.class),
    MEMOIZED(FibonacciGenerator.MemoizedFibonacciGenerator.class);

    private final Class<? extends FibonacciGenerator> algorithmClass;

    private <T extends FibonacciGenerator> Algorithm(Class<T> algorithmClass) {
        this.algorithmClass = algorithmClass;
    }
}
```

Does that do what you want?

The other option is to use an instance of the class, but after further thought I think this is a bad idea.  If you are going to use an instance of the class then why'd you need the enum in the first place?

Comment: plouh is right, a real instance of the class would be better than reflectively creating it.

Comment: Make the field final and you will get a +1 :)

Comment: I think plouh is right, an instance might be a better approach... can you modify your code to reference an instance instead of the class (please and thank-you)?

Comment: Actually on further thought, I don't see the point of this enum at all, just use an instance of the class and it does the same job.  If you want to use the approach with an instance then plouh's solution is correct (you just need to declare a private member as mentioned in the comments)

Answer (score 1):

Try providing a real instance instead of class:

```
public enum Algorithm {
    RECURSIVE (new RecursiveFibonacciGenerator()),
    ITERATIVE (new IterativeFibonacciGenerator()),
    MEMOIZED (new MemoizedFibonacciGenerator());

    private <T extends FibonacciGenerator> Algorithm(T algorithm) {}
}
```

Comment: Cool, but then how do I declare a private member variable that references the generic instance?

Comment: See the answer by @ignis below, that should do the trick with a related get method.

Answer (score 1):

Plouh is right. And you may declare and initialize a member variable just as if it were a class rather than an enum:

```
private final FibonacciGenerator _instance;

private Algorithm(FibonacciGenerator instance) {
    _instance = instance;
}
```

and then return it through a public getFibonacciGenerator() method. Notice that there is no need to use generics if you store the instance rather than the Class. And remember to declare the field as "final"

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if i understand well the question, but if you simply want to keep the strategy as member variable:

```
public enum Algorithm {
  RECURSIVE (RecursiveFibonacciGenerator.class),
  ITERATIVE (IterativeFibonacciGenerator.class),
  MEMOIZED (MemoizedFibonacciGenerator.class);

  private Class<? extends FibonacciGenerator> strategy;

  private Algorithm(Class<? extends FibonacciGenerator> algorithmClass) {
    this.strategy = algorithmClass;
  }

  Class<? extends FibonacciGenerator> getStrategy() {
    return strategy;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with the following code:

```
package com.example.strategy;

public class Fibonacci {
    private enum Algorithm {
        UNDEFINED (null),
        RECURSIVE (RecursiveFibonacciGenerator.class),
        ITERATIVE (IterativeFibonacciGenerator.class),
        MEMOIZED (MemoizedFibonacciGenerator.class);

        private final Class<? extends FibonacciGenerator> algorithmClass;
        private FibonacciGenerator instance;
        private <T extends FibonacciGenerator> Algorithm(Class<T> algorithmClass) {
            this.algorithmClass = algorithmClass;
        }

        public FibonacciGenerator getInstance() {
            if (this.instance == null) {
                try {
                    this.instance = this.algorithmClass.newInstance();
                } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return this.instance;
        }
    }

    public Integer getTerm(Integer termNumber) {
        return profileGenerator(termNumber, Algorithm.MEMOIZED);
    }

    private Integer profileGenerator(Integer termNumber, Algorithm algorithm) {
        System.out.print("Computing term using " + algorithm.toString() + " algorithm... ");
        Long startTimeMilliseconds = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Integer term = algorithm.getInstance().generateTerm(termNumber);
        Long endTimeMilliseconds = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Long computationTimeMilliseconds = endTimeMilliseconds - startTimeMilliseconds;
        System.out.println("term computed in " + computationTimeMilliseconds + " milliseconds");
        return term;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are using enums here to do something that you really shouldn't be doing.  I'd throw away the enum and use the FibonacciGenerator interface directly in profileGenerator.  You don't need the added complexity from the enum.